# Pandaify - Pythonify (Max Observation , Last Observation) Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have simple problem which I am able to solve but I think my solution is not upto standard. It is messy.
I would like to take this as a learning opportunity in simplifying the calculation.

Here is the setup.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas_datareader.data as web   

start = datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(years=1)
end = datetime.date.today()

main = ['MSFT','AAPL','FB','AMZN','NVDA','MA','V','ADBE','LULU','CRM','CRWD']

df = web.DataReader(main, 'yahoo', start, end)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',['MSFT','CRWD']]].head(5)
```

DataFrame df is the Stock Market Data for a list of tickers returned from Pandas DataReader module.

[image]

I am trying to find the percentage difference of the max Stock Price to the Last Closing Stock Price.

[image]

I use the below calculation, this is the code I need simplified.

```
(
    pd.concat( 
        [
         df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',:]].max().unstack().transpose().reset_index().set_index('Symbols').rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Max Close'}),   
         df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',:]].tail(1).stack().reset_index()[['Symbols','Adj Close']].set_index('Symbols').rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Last Close'}),
        (
          (
              (
                df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',:]].max().unstack().transpose().reset_index().set_index('Symbols')
                - df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',:]].tail(1).stack().reset_index()[['Symbols','Adj Close']].set_index('Symbols')
              )
                /
             df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',:]].tail(1).stack().reset_index()[['Symbols','Adj Close']].set_index('Symbols'))*100
        ).rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Percentage Diff'})
        ],
        axis='columns'
        )
        .sort_values(by='Percentage Diff', ascending=False)    
)
```

This is my result.

[image]

Comment: can you show what your dataframe look like? one sample

Comment: added a line and screen shot for the sample of the DataFrame. df.loc[idx[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1):],idx['Adj Close',['MSFT','CRWD']]].head(5)

Comment: @jlandercy The input sample is given by the Pandas Data Reader. The code I posted should be a reproducible example. Open Source Python  modules and internet is required.

Comment: I have seen it, anyway always copy paste data instead of screenshot. Image are poor medium for numerical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
df = df.sort_index()['Adj Close']
pdiff = 100*(df.max() - df.iloc[-1,:])/df.iloc[-1,:]
```

It returns:

```
Symbols
MSFT     7.339788
AAPL    14.713167
FB      14.921531
AMZN     7.448315
NVDA     4.241517
MA       3.775402
V        4.761903
ADBE     6.300777
LULU    14.959885
CRM      5.741029
CRWD     1.086576
dtype: float64
```

If you wish to keep your output, then create columns first and write down the operation:

```
df = df.sort_index()['Adj Close']
d = df.max().to_frame(name='max')
d['last'] = df.iloc[-1,:]
d['change'] =  100.*(d['max'] - d['last'])/d['last']
d = d.sort_values('change', ascending=False)
```

Which returns:

```
                 max         last     change
Symbols                                     
LULU      398.290009   346.459991  14.959885
FB        303.910004   264.450012  14.921531
AAPL      134.179993   116.970001  14.713167
AMZN     3531.449951  3286.649902   7.448315
MSFT      231.649994   215.809998   7.339788
ADBE      533.799988   502.160004   6.300777
CRM       281.250000   265.980011   5.741029
V         216.479996   206.639999   4.761903
NVDA      573.859985   550.510010   4.241517
MA        365.694153   352.390015   3.775402
CRWD      145.130005   143.570007   1.086576
```

Comment: I like the way you calculate percentage. Is there a way to bypass the pd.concat() I am using in my code? I am expecting a DataFrame as result with index as Symbols,3 Columns (Max Close, Last Close, Percent Difference).

Comment: @KeerikkattuChellappan, Updated to take it into account. Sorted wrt percent change.